# Transform midi pitch bend to 0 to 4 logarithmic scale

Tags: swift, math, midi

I have midi pitch bend message which needs to be transformed from a linear scale between 0 and 16368 to a logarithmic scale between 0.0 and 4.0.

I know that when the pitch bend is at 12432, the value needs to be at 1.0 and that at 16368 it should be at 4.0

How can I program a function in swift to convert between these two scales?

Comment: Pitch bend range is 0 to 16383 because it is encoded with 14 bits. But it should be interpreted as a signed integer, with a value = 8192 meaning zero bending. Why is your maximum 16368?

Comment: That might be related to the type casting by AudioKit, Ill look into that but that does not relate to my question per se

Comment: MIDI pitch bend values are already on a logarithmic scale, so this question doesn't make a lot of sense.  Also the title says 0 to 1, but 16368 should come out to 4?

Comment: I updated my title. What do you mean that pitch bend values are on a logarithmic scale? When I slide the fader up halfway, the output is around half of 16368, so that would suggest that it is outputting linear?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. But logarithm has a vertical asymptote. So, you should define the left and right bounds of abscissa. One of the possible formulas:

```
y = 4 * ln( (x + 1) * (e - 1) / 16368)
```